# how to send a value from view2 to view1

Tags: iphone, tableview

My problem is how to reload the tableview

I have 2 viewcontrollers.

In first Viewcontroller I have one tableview. if I select any row in tableview it goes to second viewcontroller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NextPageController *nextView = [[NextPageController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextPageView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nextView animated:YES];
    [nextView release];
}
```

in second view controller I have one textfield. If I enter any value into the textfield I need to disaplay that value into the first viewcontroller tableview.

can any one help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give NextPageController a protocol and a delegate,just like this:

```
@protocol (NextPageControllerDelegate)
-(void)displayString:(NSString *)inputString;
@end

@interface FirstTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    id<NextPageControllerDelegate> stringDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<NextPageControllerDelegate> stringDelegate;
```

and in the .m file:

```
@implementation
@synthesize stringDelegate;
```

then, when you alloc the NextPageViewController, insert this:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;  
{ 
    NextPageController *nextView = [[NextPageController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextPageView" bundle:nil]; 

    nextView.stringDelegate = self;

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:nextView animated:YES]; 
    [nextView release]; 
}
```

of course, your table view controller must conforms to the NextPageControllerDelegate protocol, and give the implementation of

```
-(void)displayString:(NSString *)inputString;
```

after that, when you are in nextView, and want to have the table view display that string, you may do this:

```
if(nil != self.stringDelegate)
    [self.stringDelegate displayString:someString];
```

ant then it's done

Answer (score 1):

create global `NSMutableArray`.
Store and add all data in that `NSMutableArray`.
In `-(void) viewwillappear` of first class, call `[tablename reloadData];`

Comment: i need to call this in first viewcontroller or second

Comment: The view in which you are displaying your table.

Answer (score 1):

Make Global String ,

Assign it in secondViewController and when you pop from secondViewController to FirstViewController , viewWillAppear will call.

make logic such it uses global variable and then reload table ..

Answer (score 1):

you need to have a global `NSString` variable in `appDelegate` that stores your text of text filed in second view.

Now, when you come back to previous page, in

```
- (void) viewWillAppear
{
    [yourDataSourceArray addObject:appDelegate.yourGlobalString];
    [yourTableView reloadData];
}
```

and yes make sure that your `yourDataSourceArray` is `NSMutableArray`.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a property for an NSString in your first view, and a property for an instance of the first view controller (UITableViewController?) in your second view.  Then upon saving or popping or whatever you're doing in the second view controller once you have entered the text you want, you could set the property of the NSString, pop the view, and reload the tableView in viewWillAppear.  Alternatively you could use delegation as Lewen described.